# CVS update command to get clean copy

Tags: cvs

I am using the following CVS command to get clean copy of locally modified files.

```
CVS update -P -d -C
```

While this command does get a clean copy of the locally modified files, it keeps a version of the locally modified copy in that folder.

```
Locally modified myclass.java moved to .#myclass.java.1.4
```

Is there a way to get a update without keeping a version of the local copy in the folder?

Comment: probably not possible.